# Time-tracking software, Google-calendar-style

Tags: time-management

I'm looking for a Windows or web-based time-tracking software with the following features:

- manually add time using some GUI like Google Calendar to define the time spans:

[image]

- visually see time spans as in Google Calendar.
- define a few categories (i.e. sleep/work/eat/meetings/etc.), which we can choose from when adding time.
- ability to add a note when adding time.
- basic statistics on day/week/month activity grouped by category. (that's the main reason why I cannot use Google Calendar as the time-tracking software)

Ideally:

- Gratis
- web-based + Windows
- has an Android app

---

Grindstone does not have GUI like Google Calendar to define the time spans:

[image]

I am aware of the [Wikipedia comparison of time-tracking software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_time-tracking_software).

Comment: You can create separate calendar for sleep/work/eat/meetings/etc.  Google Calendar has an API which you could to do your own statistics if you know how to program.  You can select a date range via API and sum the hours for said events and then do whatever math you want.

Answer (score 1):

## [Time Meter Time Sheet](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.rk.timemeter&hl=en)

It has all the required features. It has an separated addon to export the tracked times to Google Calendar.

This and ManicTime are my two beloved apps for tracking time. In ManicTime you can import time from Google Calendar.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I use Google Calendar every day solving work-related issue. Starting and switching tasks directly in Google Calendar are brilliant and very handy feature that saves me an ocean of time.

Given that, I’d advise you the solution that helps me a lot - [TMetric](https://tmetric.com/integrations/google-calendar-time-tracking/), Google Calendar integrated time tracker. Here is a quick look at it:

Why TMetric is extremely valuable for me:

- Timer button is integrated into each Google Calendar event
  [image]
- It takes literally a single click to start the timer
  Great time reports
- Available on Windows, Mac, and Linux

Hope you’ll find my experience useful!