# Looking for suggestion about Time block style C# libary ( Eg: Google Calendar style display )

Tags: c#, time-management, design

### Preface

Need a library to display time block ( Eg: stylegoogle calendar ) but I found nothing..

### Search Effort

Following keywords are searched on google, but it's hard to find a valid result because "block" is a synchronization related keyword. Most of time synchronization are time related... so I found nothing..

- C# time-block style library

  ==> Most of results are time related or blocking / synchronization related.
- C# time-block style framework

  ==> Same as above.
- C# Google-calendar style library

  ==> Google calendar api related..

I've found the post for [software suggestion for google calendar style](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/24690/69190) but I need a library for C#.

### Requirement

1. C# winform compatible. .Net framework 4.0+ are welcome. If there is no winform solution, wpf is also an option. No client or server. The final application which uses libraries would be a simple executable. Or any web base solutions.
2. Run on personal pc. OS: Windows 7 / 10.

[image: Example]

3. Display:

   - The libary could display different time interval like google calendar. If two blocks have intersection, they could dock aside like Task A & B. If they are on the same date, they may stack up like task C & D.
   - Color and text could be modified.
4. Interaction: Click is enough. Time blocks do not need to be draggable.

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can checkout [WinForms Scheduler](https://www.syncfusion.com/winforms-ui-controls/scheduler) control which has day view to achieve the above requirement.

Note: I work for Syncfusion.

Syncfusion also offer [free community license](https://www.syncfusion.com/products/communitylicense).